# Fast-CSV modify before loading CSV to MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, express, csv, mysql2

I am trying to load a CSV file to my MYSQL database, however before I do so I need to modify it slightly. The CSV file is Pipe delimitated (|)
I have a column in the CSV file called Party:Identification. This column has results such as "a:hello, b:hi c:151 ......" This can go on infinitely.
I only need to get the value for c. I have come up with a method that works for this, however I am stuck on how to modify the value before the file is inserted into the database.

I tried replacing all the ":" in the headers with "" and then using .transform to modify the values, however this doesn't appear to change the values in the column, only the header. Code is attached below.

```js
 csv.parseFile(req.file.path, {
        headers: headers => headers.map(function (header) {
            const newHeaders = header.replaceAll(" ", "").replaceAll(":", "")
            console.log(newHeaders)
            return newHeaders
        }),
        delimiter: '|'
    })
        .transform(function(data) {
            console.log(data)
            PartyIdentification: getPartyID(data.partyIdentification)
        })
        .on("error", (err) => console.error(err))
        .on("finish", function () {
            query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" +
                file +
                "' INTO TABLE table " +
                " FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'" +
                " LINES TERMINATED BY  '\n'" +
                " IGNORE 1 ROWS;").then(r =>
                console.log(file)
            )
        })



function getPartyID(str) {
    if (str === undefined) return ""
    const split = str.split(",")
    const value = split.find(val => {
        return val.includes("c")
    })
    if(value === undefined) return ""
    return (value.split(":")[1].trim())
}
```

Comment: Use input preprocessing in LOAD DATA.

Comment: Is `c` always the 3rd column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex to parse the value of `c:123` in a string:

```js
function getPartyID(str) {
  if (str === undefined) return "";
  const m = str.match(/\bc:([^ ]*)/); 
  return m ? m[1] : null;
}

[
  "a:hello, b:hi c:151 d:foo",
  "a:hello, b:no_c",
].forEach(str => {
  console.log(str, '==>', getPartyID(str));
});
```

Output:

```
a:hello, b:hi c:151 d:foo ==> 151
a:hello, b:no_c ==> null
```

Explanation of regex:

- `\b` -- word boundary
- `c:` -- literal text
- `([^ ]*)` -- capture group 1 with value, up to and excluding space

**UPDATE 1:** Based on additional question on how to insert modified data into MySQL, here is a solution that does not use `INFILE`, but instead loads the file into memory (here simulated with `const input`), modifies the data as needed, and constructs a SQL statement that inserts all the data. IMPORTANT: You likely want to add escapes against SQL injections.

```js
const input = `Name|Party:Identification|Date
Foo|a:hello, b:hi c:151 d:foo|2022-01-11
Bar|a:hola, b:hey c:99 d:bar|2022-01-12
Nix|a:nix, b:ni d:nix|2022-01-13`;
const partIdFieldName = 'Party:Identification';

function getPartyID(str) {
  if (str === undefined) return "";
  const m = str.match(/\bc:([^ ]*)/); 
  return m ? m[1] : 0;
}

let partIdIdx = 0;
let data = input.split(/[\r\n]+/).map((row, idx) => {
  let cells = row.split('|');
  if(idx === 0) {
    partIdIdx = cells.indexOf(partIdFieldName);
  } else {
    cells[partIdIdx] = getPartyID(cells[partIdIdx]);
  }
  return cells;
});
//console.log('data', '==>', data);

let sql = 'INSERT INTO tbl_name\n' +
 '  (' + data[0].map(val => '"' + val + '"').join(',') + ')\n' +
 'VALUES\n' +
 data.slice(1).map(row => {
   return '  (' + row.map(val => /^[\d+\.]+$/.test(val)
     ? val
     : '"' + val + '"'
   ).join(',') + ')'
 }).join('\n') + ';';
console.log(sql);
```

Output:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name
  ("Name","Party:Identification","Date")
VALUES
  ("Foo",151,"2022-01-11")
  ("Bar",99,"2022-01-12")
  ("Nix",0,"2022-01-13");
```

Comment: I am able to get the correct value, the issue is i am unsure how to make fast-csv edit the file before I upload it to the DB

Comment: Consider the regex approach faster than the split, includes, trim approach. Also your solution has false positives with a string like `"a:cello, b:hi c:151 d:foo"` because you look for `c` anywhere.

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct... I still face the issue of the fast-csv library .transform not changing it before the file is uploaded

Comment: Define a local `csvData` array, and fill it `.on("data", function(data) { csvData.push(data); })`. Do the transform in there or separately, then insert the data in mysql using `[csvData]`

Comment: I cannot use Load Data Infile then can i ? Trying to minimize the amoujnt of queries

Comment: @Christian : See UPDATE 1 based on your additional question

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother fixing the csv file before loading, simply toss the unwanted columns as you `LOAD` it.

This, for example, will load only the 3rd column:

```
LOAD DATA ...
    (@a, @b, c_col, @d, @e, ...)
```

That is, capture the unwanted columns into @variables that you will then ignore.

If you need to remove the `c:` before storing into the table, then

```
LOAD DATA ...
    (@a, @b, @c, @d, @e, ...)
    SET c_c0l = mid(@c, 3)
```

(or whatever expression will work.  See also `SUBSTRING_INDEX` in case it would work better.)

`LOAD DATA` is plenty fast, even in this wasteful mode.  And a lot less coding on your part.

Comment: The problem is "c:" is not always the third column, and the column length can change

Comment: @Christian - I need the general case, or enough examples so I can help you further.